# Get breakpoint value in bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

We currently upgraded from Bootstrap4 to Bootstrap5 in our project.

I need to get the value of a breakpoint in my ts/js which worked in BS4 with

```js
window
    .getComputedStyle(document.documentElement)
    .getPropertyValue("--breakpoint-md")
```

But it stopped working in BS5

Codesandbox examples [BS4](https://codesandbox.io/s/red-snowflake-u057nn?file=/script.js:14-110)
[BS5](https://codesandbox.io/s/bootstrap-5-forked-nujkie?file=/src/index.js)

Anyone had similar problems?

Comment: This should be a css custom property no a Sass variable of bootstrap thus the version of Bootstrap used shouldn't be the cause of the problem, you should have that custom property in your css

Comment: Look at the body tag on both of those examples. BS4 had css variables for the breakpoints, BS5 doesn't. The fix is to add them manually back in.

Comment: Please include all relevant code **in the question itself**, not only on external sites.

Answer (score 3):

### Update:

The breakpoint variables are again available out of the box since Bootstrap v5.3! They can easily be obtained with following js:

```js
getComputedStyle(document.body)
    .getPropertyValue('--bs-breakpoint-md');
```

### Previous answer:

BS4 adds all breakpoints as a variable to the root. BS5 on the other hand does not do it anymore so you need to create them yourself. To do so you should use SASS. Just add following code to your styles.scss

```scss
    :root {
        @each $breakpoint, $value in $grid-breakpoints {
            --breakpoint-#{$breakpoint}: #{$value};
        }
    }
```

The output (which can alternatively been added directly in the styles.css) will be:

```scss
    :root {
        --breakpoint-xs: 0;
        --breakpoint-sm: 576px;
        --breakpoint-md: 768px;
        --breakpoint-lg: 992px;
        --breakpoint-xl: 1200px;
        --breakpoint-xxl: 1400px;
    }
```

After that your JS should work as before.

Note: BS5 now also uses [prefixes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/css-variables/#prefix) for css variables.